# Latex: Align two tables side by side on top

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, align

As shown in the below code, the second and third table are side by side. How can I make these two tables align on the top? The rows in the second table can be more than those in the third table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[lmargin=0.80cm,rmargin=0.80cm,tmargin=2.50cm,bmargin=0.80cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{carlito}
\parindent=0pt

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\headsep=2.0mm

\newcommand{\defaultfontsize}{\fontsize{10pt}{\baselineskip}\selectfont}
\begin{document}\defaultfontsize
\begin{tabular}{@{}|l|l|l|l|l|p{2.7cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.3ex}\textbf{Characteristic dead load and live load - Point load}}\\
\hline
\rule{0pt}{2.3ex}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{DL}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{LL}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Load geometry}} & \textbf{Comment}\\
\cline{2-5}
\rule{0pt}{2.3ex}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{(kN)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{(kN)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{A(m)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{B(m)}} & \\
\hline
1 & 1.000 & 2.100 & 2.500 & 2.900 & From B1\\
\hline
2 & 1.100 & 2.200 & 1.500 & 3.900 & \\
\hline
3 & 1.200 & 2.300 & 3.500 & 1.900 & \\
\hline
4 & 1.300 & 2.400 & 4.500 & 0.900 & \\
\hline
5 & 1.400 & 2.500 & 0.300 & 5.100 & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\quad

\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{@{}|l|p{4.5cm}|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\rule{0pt}{2.3ex}
 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Load combination - ULS}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\boldmath $\mathsf{M_{max}}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\boldmath $\mathsf{R_{1}}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\boldmath $\mathsf{R_{2}}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\boldmath $\mathsf{V_{max}}$}\\
\cline{3-6}
\rule{0pt}{2.3ex}
 & $\mathsf{_{\_U}=UDL,\,_{\_C}=Concentrated}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{(kNm)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{kN}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{kN}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{kN}}\\
\hline
1 & $\mathsf{1.35DL}$ & 71.16 & 36.89 & 35.90 & 36.89\\
\hline
2 & $\mathsf{1.2DL + 1.5LL_{\_U}}$ & \textbf{160.98} & 82.12 & 84.64 & \textbf{84.64}\\
\hline
3 & $\mathsf{1.2DL + 1.5LL_{\_C}}$ & 65.48 & 33.62 & 32.73 & 33.62\\
\hline
4 & $\mathsf{1.2DL + 1.5\ \psi_{\mathit{l\_U}}\ LL_{\_U}}$ & 63.26 & 32.79 & 31.91 & 32.79\\
\hline
5 & $\mathsf{1.2DL + 1.5\ \psi_{\mathit{l\_C}}\ LL_{\_C}}$ & 63.26 & 32.79 & 31.91 & 32.79\\
\hline
6 & $\mathsf{0.9DL + W_{u\_up}}$ & 11.07 & 3.54 & 7.29 & 7.29\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{@{}|l|p{4.5cm}|l|}
\hline
\rule{0pt}{2.3ex}
 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Load combination - SLS}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\boldmath $\mathsf{\updelta_{max}}$}\\
\rule{0pt}{2.3ex}
 & $\mathsf{_{\_U}=UDL,\,_{\_C}=Concentrated}$ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{(mm)}}\\
\hline
1 & $\mathsf{DL}$ & 5.18\\
\hline
  2 & $\mathsf{LL_{\_U}}$ & 6.45\\
\hline
  3 & $\mathsf{LL_{\_C}}$ & 0.12\\
\hline
4 & $\mathsf{DL + \psi_{\mathit{s\_U}}\ LL_{\_U}}$ & 9.70\\
\hline
5 & $\mathsf{DL + \psi_{\mathit{s\_C}}\ LL_{\_C}}$ & 5.30\\
\hline
6 & $\mathsf{DL + \psi_{\mathit{l\_U}}\ LL_{\_U}}$ & 5.18\\
\hline
7 & $\mathsf{DL + W_{s\_up}}$ & 3.35\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: use the `[t]` option to align tops

Comment: To expand on @jsbibra's comment: change `\begin{tabular}{...}` to `\begin{tabular}[t]{...}`.

Comment: @ Mico, clear explanation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

Edit the code of the second and third table as follows

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}|l|p{4.5cm}|l|l|l|l|}
   ......
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}|l|p{4.5cm}|l|}
   ......
\end{tabular}
```

Rest of the code remains same